# Some applications displaying squares instead of ideographs

Tags: windows-7, fonts, language, unicode, characters

I have a Windows 7 x64. I noticed, that in some applications I have squares instead of Asian languages characters. 
E.g. in MS Word, in Chrome, in Skype ideographs look fine. I also installed Japanese language pack. It works fine too and I'm able to typing in Japanese.

But in AIMP, file explorer (in particular, folders names) and Notepad++ (text file is encoded to UTF-8) I have only squares. And the problem in general exists with Asian ideographs and some other characters:

> E.g. ™, ▲, ¼ looks fine, but ℍ, ①, ︷ are also displayed as squares.

I know, tht this is not the first same question, and I've found 2 possible solutions:

1. > Control Panel --> All Control Panel Items --> Fonts --> Font settings
   >
   > Hide fonts based on language settings - **disable** it.

   Hide fonts based on language settings is **disabled**, but problem still exists.

2. > Change the system locale.

But I don't think it's a pretty good. My current system locale is Russian, and I think, even if I would fix the problem with Asian languages, I could have some problems with Russian instead.

So, is there another solution? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked the font you are using in NotePad++ actually has the unicode characters you are trying to type?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried to set PmingLiU font - japanese characters look fine, that bracket too ︷.
Ok, the problem is with fonts, but how can I set this font (or another font, that supports japanese) as default system font for asian characters? In addition, AIMP also uses font without japanese support, and I can't see any option in settings to change the font.

Comment: [MS Mincho font](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=206) supports more code pages than [PMingLiU font](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1770) incl. OEM-Russian and ANSI-Cyrillic.